# Some php code not working after moving to Plesk from Cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel, plesk

Recently, my web host offers me to switch to Plesk from Cpanel, they said Plesk is very good, and their new plan is using Plesk control panel and Litespeed server that helps to boost my website load speed. And, I agreed to give it a try.

Now, the problem is the php code that I used on my website not working. It was working pretty fine when it was in cpanel. I ask their support tech to fix that for me, now they asking me back is my code not compatible with Litespeed. But, I have another website hosted by other web hosting company that uses Litespeed server but they are Cpanel. The same php code working fine too. So, I don't think it's coding issue. They tech support unable to get it fixed for me. Frustrated!

Does anybody know what's going wrong?

Here is the code

```
<?
$s=$_GET['Submission'];
if ($s=="failed") {
   echo ('<p class="errorMessage">Ops! Something went wrong at the Math question. Please try again with correct answer!</p>');
   }
?>
<?
$s=$_GET['Submission'];
if ($s=="success") {
   echo ('<style>.hide {display:none;}.submitted {background:#9dd100; padding:5px 8px; color:#fff;}</style>');
   echo ('<p class="submitted ms">Enquiry form has been submitted successfully. Please allow us to have some time for reviewing, and we will revert to you as soon as possible. Thank you!<br/><span class="note">[This message will be closed in 15 seconds.]</span></p>');
   }
?>
```

This code is actually a simple code for me to hide the error and success message when submitting the form.

Now it's not working. Not sure if anything else I can do for Plesk to make it work?

Here is the screenshot of the website.
https://snipboard.io/DypiJH.jpg

Appreciate your kind feedback.

Comment: The PHP short_open_tag `<? ?>` may be disabled in Plesk. Please follow these steps in https://conetix.com.au/support/plesk-enable-php-short-open-tag/

Comment: Hi! Thank you! It works now. :)

Comment: Try to avoid using the short open tag for compatibility.

Comment: But I need that code. But, how do I replace them using others?

Comment: Replace `<?` with `<?php`

Comment: Okay, Noted. I will do it accordingly. Thank you! :)